# Assign value based on a condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling two functions and checking if the given input has `barcode` and `qr code`

```
var decode = jsQR.decodeQRFromImage(rawImageData.data, rawImageData.width, rawImageData.height);
checkBarCode(function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        Result.pages.push({
            ValidTicket: decode ? true : false //here i want to assign true or false if barcode or qr code is present.
        });
    }
});
```

is this correct?

```
ValidTicket: decode  || result ? true : false
```

Comment: Seems correct to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assignment does work correctly, but I might suggest using two boolean NOT operators instead, which is slightly terser:

```
var decode = jsQR.decodeQRFromImage(
  rawImageData.data,
  rawImageData.width,
  rawImageData.height
);

checkBarCode(function(err, result) {
    if (result) {
        Result.pages.push({
            ValidTicket: !!(decode || result)
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. If **either** `decode` or `result` is truthy*, you'll assign `true`; if both are falsy*, you'll assign `false`.

You may get someone telling you to just do this:

```
ValidTicket: decode || result
```

...but that won't necessarily assign either `true` or `false`, because of JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*; instead, it'll assign the value of `decode` if it's truthy, and the value of `result` if not. So if you really need `true` or `false`, you need to use the conditional as you have done.

---

* About "truthy" and "falsy":

"truthy" - a value that coerces to `true` when used as a boolean

"falsy" - a value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean

The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and (of course), `false`. All other values are truthy.